# How to insert a value in the same line sqlite3 using python

Tags: python, sqlite

i have two function (in python). The first function defines a new variable which i have to insert in a sql table (first column). The second one, does the same thing, but i want to insert its variable (the second one) near the first variable, so in the second column but in the same line. How can i do with sql?.

```
connloc = sqlite3.connect("request.db")
sqlloc = "create table requests (" \
" chat_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"\
" locpar varchar(20)," \
" stoppar varchar(20)," \
" locdes varchar(20) ," \
" stopdes varchar(20) );"
connloc.execute(sqlloc)

def name_loc(chat, message):
    for i in result:
        if message.text == i:
            item = [i]
            cloc = connloc.cursor()
            cloc.execute("INSERT INTO requests(locpar) VALUES (?);", item)
            connloc.commit()

def name_stop(chat, message):
    for i in result:
     for t in result[i]:
        if message.text == t:
            item = [t]
            cloc = connloc.cursor()
            cloc.execute("INSERT INTO requests(stoppar) VALUES (?);", item)
            connloc.commit()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would break it up into a two step process by defining two methods, one for table generation and then another second method for populating the new table like this:

```
def create_table(ptbl):

    """ Assemble DDL (Data Definition Language) Table Create statement and build
        sqlite3 db table

    Args:
        string: new db table name.

    Returns:
        Status string, '' or 'SUCCESS'.
    """
    retval = ''
    sqlCmd = ''
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
        c = conn.cursor()

        if ptbl == 'TBL_EXAMPLE':
            sqlCmd = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' + ptbl + ' (FIELD1 TEXT, FIELD2 INTEGER, FIELD3 TEXT, ' \
                                                            'FIELD4 TEXT, FIELD5 TEXT)'
        else:
            pass

        if sqlCmd != '':
            c.execute(sqlCmd)
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()

        retval = 'SUCCESS'

    except Error as e:

        retval = 'FAIL'
        print(e)

    return retval
```

and then populate it as you like with the values (inserting your new row with those two specific values you mentioned).

Now, I'm populating from a csv file here, but I thinkit'll give you a really good solid start on this task.

```
def populate_tbl_file_marker_linenums(p_fml_tbl, p_fml_datafile):
    """ Read csv and load data into TBL_FILE_MARKER_LINENUMS table ...

    Args:
        p_fml_tbl (TEXT) target table name
        p_fml_datafile (TEXT) name of csv file to load into table

    Returns:
        retval (TEXT) - Status of method, e.g., 'SUCCESS'
    """
    retval = ''
    mode = 'r'

    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
        c = conn.cursor()
        csv_dataset = open(p_fml_datafile, mode)
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_dataset)

        c.executemany('INSERT INTO ' + p_fml_tbl + ' (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3, FIELD4, FIELD5) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', csv_reader)

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        retval = 'SUCCESS'

    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return retval
```